# I have a transparent jpeg? I'm confused

Tags: transparency, texture, jpeg

Not sure if this is the right place as I'm new to Stack Exchange but I was messing around with a discord bot that had a Minecraft texture tiling feature and I got 2 transparent jpeg files from it.
I'm just wondering how this is possible

[image: one of them]

[image: the other one]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's not a JPG. It's a PNG. I suspect what you have is PNG which has just had the extension changed to JPG.  Changing a file extension doesn't change the format.

Answer (score 1):

Save a PNG...

...then, using the Mac Finder or Windows Explorer, change the suffix from `png` to `jpg`.

Result a transparent PNG file with a jpg suffix - *not* an actual jpg.

Comment: ohh okay, though i have tried that before and it never worked, oh well thanks for the explanation